# VBA for Excel - Trying to round to nearest 500, cannot get code to round correctly at 250

Tags: vba, excel

Please accept my sincerest apologies if the title or question is confusing.

I am using VBA in Excel 2007.  I need to round a number to the nearest 500.

I am using the code:

```
Rvariable = Round(variable / 500, 0) * 500
```

My available numbers that I am trying to round go from `-500` to `10000`. 
If the value to be rounded is from `501` to `749`, it will round down appropriately (i.e. `2501` to `2749` rounds to `500`). `750's` appropriately round up (`2750` rounds to `3000`).  Values from `001` to `249` also round down correctly, and `251` to `499` round up correctly.

For some reason, a `250` value still rounds down (`2250` rounds to `2000` not `2500`).  It will not round up until `251`.  When I use this function in the actual excel worksheet, the `Round` function works properly and will round up at `250`.

Comment: `Rvariable = Application.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(variable, 500)`. Your way does not work because of [floating point precision](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21895756/11683).

Comment: In addition to GSerg's comment, when you Round(2250/ 500, 0), it gives 4 instead of 4.5, thus 4 * 500 = 2000. Round(2251/500) gives 5, where 5*500 = 2500.

Comment: [Rvariable = Application.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(variable, 500)]  will not work in my situation since anything above each set of [500] goes to the next [500] (i.e. [8001] goes to [8500] when it should go to [8000])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vba doesn't round in the traditional sense I learned(a bit of a hack) to add 0.000001. so you're not changing your code much by doing the below

```
Rvariable = Round((variable + 0.000001) / 500, 0) * 500
```

it isn't a significant amount and you shouldn't experience any calculation errors. although you'd probaly have to add in some logic for doing negatives -0.000001 instead for negative numbers

Comment: So now 500 will round to 1000. Also VBA [does round in the traditional sense](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194983/en-us), it's just there is more than one traditional sense.

Comment: no 500 will stil be 500 but Yes @GSerg great link I do need to broaden my traditions. but yeah this version leaves the issue in place for negatives so kind of getting away from my idea of not changing zigs code much. sadface